# How can i check, if a user input from python already exists in a database / table?

Tags: python, mysql, authentication

**First**: So i want to write a login system in python, and my problem is, i dont know, how to check, if a username that was entered by a user, already exists in the accounts table.

```
def displayMenu():
    status = input("Are you registered user? y/n? : ")
    if status == 'n':
        register()



def register():
    print("Connection to databse...")
    try:
        db = mysql.connect(host=_HOST, port=_PORT, username=_USER, 
                           password=_PASS, database=_DB)
    print("Successfully connected to database..")

    except mysql.Error as e:
        print(Fore.RED + "Connection failure...")
        print(Fore.RED + "Please contact your administrator...")

    
    cmd = db.cursor()
    username = input("Enter a username:")
    cmd.execute("SELECT * from accounts WHERE username="
    # i want to check, if the entered username already exists in the database
    # i dont know, how to do that.
```

**Second**: How do i check later if username and password is correctly entered from the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just concatenate username with SELECT command to get a completed
SQL command that will return an item with username you asked for (if it exists)

```py
username = input("Enter a username:")
cmd.execute(f"SELECT * from accounts WHERE username='{username}'")
# if username is '123', then completed command will look like this:
# SELECT * from accounts WHERE username='123'
if cmd.fetchall(): # checking if something found with this username
    print('Username already exists')
```

Note: this code is not safe for usage in real life situations!

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Well, yes, but i thought the question was not about security but about how to check if username is already exists. Anyway, you're right

Comment: how can i do this more secure? maybe you can add me on discord, its better to comuticate! chrisssss#1175 Note: im at the beginning of python programming

Comment: @Vinegret43, sure, but not specifying the drawbacks of your approach to a beginner leaves them susceptible to using your approach in _real_ code. It's always better to mention what situations your answer shouldn't be applied in.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it the way [Vinegret43 suggested in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63998193/843953) is *not secure*, because it leaves your program vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), as demonstrated in [this brilliant XKCD comic](https://xkcd.com/327/)

The *correct* way to do this is to use parameters in your query. [This functionality already exists in the `MySQLdb` module that you're using.](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples)

```
select_query = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username=%s"

username = input("Enter a username: ")
cmd.execute(select_query, (username,))

selected_rows = cmf.fetchall()
```

To also check for password, you simply have to do

```
select_query = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username=%s AND password=%s"

username = input("Enter your username: ")
password = input("Enter your password: ")
cmd.execute(select_query, (username, password))

selected_rows = cmf.fetchall()
```

Note that saving passwords as plain text in your database is also a bad idea, but encryption and password security are outside the scope of your question.